# Some files on the server may be missing or incorrect. Clear browser cache and try again. If the problem persists please contact website author

Tags: web, firefox

[image: Some files on the server may be missing or incorrect. Clear browser cache and try again. If the problem persists please contact website author.]

I have this popup window showing on my website in Firefox.

It is indeed a system window displayed by the browser, not by the page.
There is no useful information in the console.

What may cause it and what can I do about it?

Comment: can you guide us how to replicate this error ? any steps ?

Comment: I wish I could, I don't usually develop in Firefox, just occasionally test my products there. I guess it started popping up after some update.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache memory ?

Comment: May be this can help : https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1123068

Comment: I have reports from other users having the same window, so even if I do it, it won't solve the problem.

Comment: Are you having any issue on a particular website ?

Comment: It shows up only on a specific website and to any Firefox user, so it's not a problem on my local PC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192357/discussion-between-jlblca9l-kpblca-and-dinesh-suthar).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this today. It came from `window.Muse.assets.check` being unable to verify some script in a list of those required. I believe that this is [Adobe Muse](http://muse.adobe.com/), which appears to be a library of widgets (like slideshows and effects).